# Want to show that a solution to some ODE is unique.

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

So here is my problem,

I just found the solution $x(t)=\frac{1}{t^2+1}$ to the following differential equation,$$ \dot{x}=-2tx^2,\;x(0)=1$$
Now I would like to show that my solution is unique and I do not know how to do this correctly. Is there maybe some theorem I am missing? Can someone help me?

Comment: Picard-Lindelöf? Heard of Lipschitz conditions?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem

Comment: Ah ok, thank you for the fast answer.

Comment: Your solution does not satisfy the initial conditions and Picard-Lindelof theorem is a clear overkill in this situation.

Comment: @Artem I just corrected it, thx.

Comment: @Artem Why overkill?

Comment: @DanielFischer Because an honest proof that a separable ODE has a unique solution in a domain, where the right hand sides are continuous and such that $f(t,x)=f_1(t)f_2(x)$, $f_2(x)\neq 0$, is a very good exercise for a first course in ODE, whereas P-L theorem is too advanced

Comment: @Artem Picard-Lindelöf was one of the first things we learned about ODEs, before techniques like separation of variables were introduced. I agree that a uniqueness proof for a separable ODE is a good exercise, but not with the assertion that Picard-Lindelöf is advanced.

Comment: @DanielFischer Did you learn the statement of this theorem or a statement with a proof?

Comment: @Artem Theorems that were stated without proof only occurred much later in the curriculum. In the first semesters, every theorem came with a proof.

Comment: @DanielFischer Then I can only say that the times have changed, and in the most courses on ODE I know of (and teach) the theorem of PL is stated in the beginning, whereas the proof either delegated to the very end, or to the literature, or, usually, to the more advanced courses. And I never heard about the course where the PL theorem would be proved first before separation of the variable technique (and know no such textbooks of any level).

Comment: @Artem Could also be a geographic distinction. I've heard that in the USA (and probably in some other places) people start with proof-less courses on sequences, series, differentiation, integration and such. That wasn't so here, proofs from the start.

Comment: @DanielFischer That is a possibility, but my own course also was not in US, and before proving the existence and uniqueness, we went through elementary techniques of solving ODE, including separation of the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose some $f$ satisfies the equation. Then $f$ must be continuous, so from $f(0)\ne0$ we know that $f(t)\ne0$ on some open interval $(a,b)$ containing $0$. Choose $(a,b)$ to be maximal such that $f(t)\ne0$ on $(a,b)$, then

$$f'(t)=-2tf^2(t)\Longleftrightarrow\frac{f'(t)}{f^2(t)}=-2t\Longleftrightarrow-\frac1{f(t)}=-t^2-c\Longleftrightarrow f(t)=\frac1{t^2+c}$$
For some $c\in\mathbb R$ (it's $1$ from the conditions). If $a\ne-\infty$ or $b\ne\infty$, then $\lim\limits_{t\to a_+}f(t)=\frac1{a^2+c}\ne0$ or $\lim_{t\to b_-}f(t)=\frac1{b^2+c}\ne0$, so $(a,b)$ wasn't maximal.

Therefore $(a,b)=(-\infty,\infty)$ and your solution is unique.